# ¿Como convertir cadena con formato JSON a cadena con formato XML?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, xml

Nesecito convertir un objeto JSON a una cadena con Formato XML , Como puedo hacer esto?

Intente con este codigo pero no me esta funcionado, me devuelve un error que dice que nesecito un path para leer el archivo Xml, ademas creo que estoy creando es un archivo xml y en realidad lo que nesecito es la cadena con formato XML.

```
 private XmlDocument XmlCreate(string cadena)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            try
            {
                doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
                doc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
                doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(cadena);
            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string n = ex.ToString();
            }
            return doc;
        }
```

Comment: Esto te será de utilidad: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm

Answer (score 3):

Creo que depende un poco de la estrutura del `xml` que quieras convertir, peor por ejemplo algo como esto

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"{peronas: [
                            {nombre:'juan', edad:20}, 
                            {nombre:'pedro', edad:50}]
                         }";

        XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");

        Console.WriteLine(doc.InnerXml);
    }
}
```

da como repuesta un xml:

```
<root>
    <peronas>
        <nombre>juan</nombre>
        <edad>20</edad>
    </peronas>
    <peronas>
        <nombre>pedro</nombre>
        <edad>50</edad>
    </peronas>
</root>
```

Pero con el `InnerXml` del `XmlDocument` puede obtener el xml como string